# Modular Multiplicative inverse of exact multiples

Tags: modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-function

How to calculate the inverse of $23$ with respect to mod 138. I am having difficulty because $138$ is an exact multiple of $138$. If anybody could help me.

Comment: It doesn't have an inverse just because it's a divisor of 138.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois is it like the numbers should satisfy condition gcd(a,n) = 1

Comment: Yes, you need that if your modulus is $n$, then $a$ will have an inverse if and only if $(a,n)=1$ to obtain an inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have an inverse because it's a divisor of 138. If your modulus is $n$, then $a$ will have an inverse if and only if $(a,n)=1$.